# Was my opponent in check?

Tags: beginner, check

I’m new to chess and I had my queen on the left one space away from the king which was on the right and he was unprotected, is that check?

E.g., take the following sample position (note: not provided by the OP - if the OP would like to post the position they had in mind, please feel free to delete this edit):

```
8/8/8/8/2Qk4/8/8/2R3K1 w - - 0 1
```

Comment: Protest!  Is there no code of conduct for editors?  If there is, it should say 'don't modify a posting, especially not by a first-time poster, beyond what normal editorial polishing requires: spelling, minor grammar, etc.'  Adding a diagram, without even knowing that it reflects the OP's intentions ... even with an added notice ... is indefensible .  (Is there a way to down-vote edits like this?)

Answer (score 10):

After making your move, imagine it's your turn again. Would your queen be able to capture the enemy king? If yes, your opponent is in check. It also doesn't matter if some other piece protects that square or not.

If there's no legal move your opponent can do do remove their king from the danger, then you're not just giving check, but also checkmate!